# Not able to connect to Remote JMX from visualVM

Tags: java, monitoring, rmi, jmx, visualvm

I am trying to connect to JMX running on Linux machine from the visualVM running on windows machine. I am using following settings for visualVM.

```
java -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.security.policy=~/jmx.all.policy  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<mymachinesIP> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8766 myApp
```

*myApp starts correctly*

security policy file is as follows :

```
grant {

   permission java.security.AllPermission;

};
```

> netstat -an | grep 9000  // doesn't return anything i.e. port is not open

I tried everything on these forums but still not able to find any solution. Any help will be appreciated. Jstatd works fine though.

Comment: I have several questions. Is firewall enabled on the Linux box? What does it mean that 'jstad' works fine? Also note that '-Djava.security.policy' has nothing to do with JMX and it could be omitted.